# During Star Trek TOS were there only 12 Constitution-class starships in all of Starfleet?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

I'm trying to get a feel for the size of the [Federation](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/United_Federation_of_Planets) during the time of [The Original Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Original_Series).

The following commentator [writes](https://twitter.com/ianrichetti/status/929895882245500928) that during the time of TOS there were only 12 Constitution class warships.

My question is: **During Star Trek TOS were there only 12 Constitution-class starships in all of Starfleet?**

Comment: Not that weird, there's only one Zumwalt class destroyer, but don't go thinking that navy is weak.

Comment: @Davidw No, the two completed and one under construction are all there are going to be. The other 29 were cancelled long ago.

Comment: And of course there aren't just large capital ships.  In addition to battleships (which is effectively what Constitution-class ships are), you need cruisers, destroyers, corvettes, minelayers/sweepers, in addition to auxiliary ships like tugs, fleet oilers/colliers (there must be some future variant of them), etc.

Comment: While designated "heavy cruisers" in the semi-canon "Star Fleet Technical Manual", the Constitution class seems to have been the most prestigious ships in Starfleet at the time; the US Navy today fields 11 nuclear-powered aircraft carriers out of a fleet of 459 ships.

Comment: On _Star Trek Discovery_, Burnham references the _Constitution_ Class (and specifically the _Enterprise_) as the type of ship Tilly could end up on if she performs well, essentially stating that a posting to one of them is considered a really big deal to Starfleet personnel.

Comment: Here is a link to a similar thread: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175411/during-star-trek-tos-how-many-starships-were-there-in-all-of-starfleet/175437#175437(https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175411/during-star-trek-tos-how-many-starships-were-there-in-all-of-starfleet/175437#175437)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, at least according to Kirk.

> **CHRISTOPHER:** *Must have taken quite a lot to build a ship like this.*
>
> **KIRK:** *There are only twelve like it in the fleet.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: Tomorrow is Yesterday](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/21.htm)</sup></sub>

That being said, when we learn of the USS Defiant (no, not [that one](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(2370)), [the earlier one](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(NCC-1764))) there may have actually been 13 ***or more***, although some are known to have been destroyed or fallen out of operation.

Within the series we actually see (or hear about) 13 Constitution class vessels, although at least two are known to have been destroyed.

- The NCC-1700 (identified as the 'USS Constitution' in the Official Fact Files - Referred to in *TOS: Space Seed*)
- USS Constellation (*TOS: The Doomsday Machine*)
- USS Defiant (Destroyed in *TOS: The Tholian Web*)
- USS Enterprise (Appears in lots of episodes)
- USS Excalibur (Appears in *TOS: The Ultimate Computer*)
- USS Exeter (Appears in *TOS: The Omega Glory*)
- USS Farragut (Destroyed in *TOS: Obsession*)
- USS Hood (Appears in *TOS: The Ultimate Computer*)
- USS Intrepid  (Appears in *TOS: Court Martial* + *The Immunity Syndrome*)
- USS Lexington (Appears in *TOS: The Ultimate Computer*)
- USS Potemkin (Appears in *TOS: The Ultimate Computer*)
- USS Republic (Appears in *TOS: Court Martial*)
- USS Yorktown (Appears in *TOS: Obsession*)

A significant number of [other Constitution-Class ships](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Constitution_class#Ships_commissioned) were mentioned in the various films and episodes that occurred after *TOS: Tomorrow is Yesterday* including the the USS Eagle and the replacement USS Enterprise.

Comment: _"12 like it"_ could be interpreted as '12', but also as 'this one and 12 others' (or 13).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Indeed. And it could also mean "12 *exactly* like it".

Comment: On those [footnotes](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Constitution_class#Footnotes), second column we got those eleven names: Enterprise, Essex, Excalibur, Lexington, Yorktown, Endeavor, Eagle, Constellation, Hornet, Wasp, Lafayette.

Comment: @Cœur - If you follow the link at the bottom of the answer, you can see each of the ships and their relevant MA pages.

Comment: Well, the Defiant appears 2 years (well, 22 months by broadcast date, but close enough) *after* Kirk says that there are only 12 like it - so more *may* have been built by then...

Comment: It should be noted that Kirk also spoke of, it his talk with Christopher, of the United Earth Space Probe Agency (UESPA).  I've always taken that to mean that Earth's fleet had 12 Connie class ships, but that the Federation could potentially have more.  Like when a US military outfit gets assigned to the UN.

Answer (score 12):

According to *The Making of Star Trek* page 165, " The following names have been established for starships: Enterprise, Exeter, Excalibur, Lexington, Yorktown, Potemkin, Republic, Hood, Constitution, Kongo, Constellation, Farragut, Valiant, and Intrepid. The latter four are listed as destroyed in various episodes."

I do not know why the book lists fourteen names it was written by Stephen E. Whitfield and Gene Roddenberry. There are two memos in the book to Gene from D.C. Fontana and Bob Justman with other suggested names for starships.

Comment: Why does your list of the "original 12" have 14 names?

Comment: One of the memos says explicitly that it presumes destroyed Starships would be replaced. There would be only twelve at any time, but maybe fourteen over the period of TOS.

Answer (score 1):

No there were 12 like the Enterprise (Constitution class) at the time of the episode "Tommorrow is Yesterday" when Kirk utters the line: "There are only twelve like it in the fleet."

The Star Trek Writer's guide established there were fourteen Constitution Class starships: Constitution, Constellation, Enterprise, Yorktown, Lexington, Farragut, Republic, Intrepid, Exeter, Hood, Excalibur, Valiant, Kongo, Potemkin.
The original AMT model decal sheet validates these names.

The Constitution Class had been around for at least 13 years and probably longer (The Menagerie) and Kirk had served aboard at least two of them before assuming command of the Enterprise. The USS Republic (Court Martial) and the USS Farragut (Obsession.)

It is almost certain the Farragut was lost or destroyed when it encountered the Cloud Creature, and that would make Kirk's statement in Tomorrow is Yesterday true when he said it. There were only twelve like it (that were left) in the fleet.

The Star Trek Reference manual lists four as destroyed. We saw at least two of them destroyed, Intrepid in Immunity Syndrome and  Constellation in Doomsday Machine. These episodes occurred after Tomorrow Is Yesterday. We heard of the destruction of Farragut in Obsession. We also probably saw the destruction of the Excalibur in Ultimate Computer but it was never established that it was destroyed beyond salvage.

This leaves the Valiant. This is problematic. It may be bad writing. Other than the ship named 'Valiant' that disappeared two hundred years before the episode 'Where No Man Has Gone Before' we saw no Constitution class USS Valiant.
We did however see a USS Defiant (Tholian Web) that wasn't on the writer's guide list.
Like the other ship names used from history there was an actual British battleship named Valiant.
There was never an actual ship named 'Defiant.' There was a fictional HMS Defiant in the film 'Damn The Defiant'
I think somebody messed up, meant to type Valiant but chose to type Defiant instead and it became hard to explain canon.

Either way there were fourteen original Constitution Class and thirteen left when Kirk made his statement in Tomorrow Is Yesterday.

And they were all Constitution class. The model gave you a Constitution class starship and 14 names to choose from.

Comment: But Kirk said "There are only twelve like it in the fleet" not "There are only twelve _others_ like it in the fleet."  The way that is said, there are 12 total, not 13.  Can you explain the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers are focused on naming the original Constitution  class starships.  I'd like to focus on the question's incredulity regarding such a small number and what people should think what the rest of the fleet looks like per "I'm trying to get a feel for the size of the Federation during the time of The Original Series".  This is a photo of the Enterprise with the Antares from "Charlie X" remastered.  The new CGI effect was based on a cargo ship from the animated series.  Point being that in its time the Constitution class was as much of a technology leap as the Galaxy class was 75 years later over older classes.  And in TNG the original intent was to only have a dozen Galaxy class ships in the fleet too.

Starships are expensive even in a post scarcity society - they take a decade to design and build and require crew.  Before JJ the adults in charge of star trek realized you can't just launch thousands of these and have them maneuver underwater.

[image: enterprise and antares]

[image: Andrew Probert Enterprises]

Answer (score -1):

Here is a link to [a similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/175411/during-star-trek-tos-how-many-starships-were-there-in-all-of-starfleet):

And [my summary](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/175437) should be noted:

> Finally, it should be remembered that there are three separate things in the era of TOS:  Starships, Constitution Class ships, and the Twelve like the *Enterprise*.
>
> It is common to assume that the three are all the same, that Starships equate to  Constitution Class ships that equate to the Twelve like the *Enterprise*.
>
> But it is possible that only two of them are the same.
>
> Thus:
>
> 1. Starships could equal Constitution Class ships and be different from the Twelve like the *Enterprise*.
> 2. Starships could equal the Twelve like the *Enterprise* and be different from Constitution class ships.
> 3. Constitution Class ships could equal the Twelve like the *Enterprise* and be different from starships.
>
> or:
>
> All three - Starships, Constitution Class ships, and the Twelve like the *Enterprise* - could be different and separate, some being subcategories of others perhaps.

Answer (score -2):

12 Constitution Class Starships:

- USS Constitution. NCC-1700
- USS Enterprise. NCC-1701 Flagship of Starfleet Command
- USS Farragut. NCC-1702
- USS Lexington. NCC-1703
- USS Yorktown. NCC-1704
- USS  Excalibur. NCC-1705
- USS Exeter. NCC-1706
- USS Hood. NCC-1707
- USS Intrepid. NCC-1708 Vulcan Crew
- USS Valiant. NCC-1709
- USS Kongo. NCC-1710
- USS Potemkin. NCC-1711

Other TOS Starships

- USS Eagle. NCC-956
- USS Republic. NCC-1371
- USS Constellation. NCC-1017
- USS Defiant. NCC-1764

Comment: I've edited this into a list to make it more readable. If you want to roll it back or make any further changes you can [edit] your own post.